# Realm: Stuck in a Shopping Application Project

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Trying my hands at Realm for the first time. As for now, I've successfully created User Sign in/Up feature in my android application using Realm Cloud Sync(firstly signing in the user using credentials using

> SyncCredentials myCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(username, password, boolean),

where boolean  reprents whether we have to create new user or not, and then creating a cloud instance for each signed in user as folllows:

> SyncUser syncUser = SyncUser.current();
>   String serverURL = "https://foodapp.us1.cloud.realm.io/~/foodie";
>   SyncConfiguration syncConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, serverURL).build();
>   Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(syncConfiguration);

where "foodie" is cloud instance where each users' realm shall be created.

But now im stuck. I have no idea how to create a univeral "products" page which can be accessed by all, how the products will be added to cart. If some one can guide me through this, it will be really helpful...